# Why doesn't the Mac App Store Twitter app (v. 2.0.2) work well with Spaces?

Tags: macos, mac, spaces, twitter

It's something that drives me crazy. The current version (2.0.2) of the official Twitter app for Mac OS X doesn't behave well with Spaces. It moves from space to space when I select another application (switching with cmd TAB.)

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to wait for a new release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the reviews of the app it seems to be a bug so you will have to wait.

You could try its predecessor [Tweetie](http://www.atebits.com/tweetie-mac/) which I think is much better.

Comment: I also liked Tweetie better in some aspects, but unfortunately it doesn't support native retweets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Twitter to stay in one Space, you can [assign it to that Space in the Spaces PrefPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrx7v.png). The downside to this is that you have to remove and re-add that assignment every time you launch Twitter. Can't wait for this bug to be fixed.

Comment: Bless you, Scott Jackson. Be the change you want to see in the world. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should also pay attention to the excellent Kiwi app. I wrote a review of this app a few months ago, which has more customization options than the Twitter and Tweetie

[Kiwi](http://kiwi-app.net/) is gorgeous and so easy to use!

Comment: Nice app! I'll give it a try. PS: you should change the link to the site's official URL: http://kiwi-app.net/

Answer (score 1):

[Twitterific](http://twitterrific.com/iphone) is what I use for OS X. As a spaces user, I can assure you it plays nicely. It costs $10 which is a little steep but there is an advertisement version so you can try before you buy. Or you could just use it until Twitter for Mac is fixed. ;) Very nice user experience in my opinion.